# SQLite selecting date, with different date-format

Tags: android, sqlite, date, select

I'm trying to select items by date, but their format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.
I thought this would work (from other threads on stackoverflow), but it doesnt:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOG_WORKOUT + " WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', " + KEY_DATE_BEGIN + ") = " + date;
```

- TABLE_LOG_WORKOUT being the table.
- KEY_DATE_BEGIN being the YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS-dates.
- date being the YYYY-MM-DD im trying to find results with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` is a string literal and needs to be put in single quotes. Or better yet, use `?` placeholder and bind arguments.

There's no syntax error since something like `2014-11-27` is a valid expression that evaluates to the integer 1976.

Comment: I should probably add, that this is written in Android/Java. Putting single-quotes around date gives a red-line underneath. If i put it inside the double-quotes, it doesn't seem to recognize the date as the input-variable.

Comment: This is what @Iaalto means: `") = '" + date + "'";` OR (better) `") = ?";` (you have then to pass the bound parameter `date`)

Comment: Of course. Iaalto is one of our greatest experts in SQLite (in good company with CL).